# Check for user level in reactJs routing

Tags: reactjs

I am updating and old application to have a log in and user roles

I am looking at what I know as an "adminGuard", in this:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <main>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path='/' component={Wizard}/>
              <Route exact path='/login' component={Login}/>
              <Route exact path='/admin' component={Admin}/>
              <Route exact path='/details' component={Details}/>
etc
```

So, if not logged it, they will be sent there - and I want to keep the link they had to so I can send them to the right page
And they can only go to what they are allowed to

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react-router v5 (i think that because the Switch tag) you can use the `useHistory` hook and use the `history.goBack()` that moves the pointer in the history stack 1 entry before.